# js / jquery particles cannot set particle direction particle.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, particle-system

I am using particle js.

I can create particle effects.

As shown here http://jsfiddle.net/hdH7b/

The problem im having is setting the direction for individual particles.If you look at the code you'll see

```
 direction: 0;           // initial start direction
 directionVariance: 45,  // +/- direction (random)
```

Which is setting all particles to move in the direction of 0, which is upwards/with a variance of 45 / 45 degrees left/right.

What I would like is to control each particle idividually. I do this by

```
  onDraw: function(p) {}    // onDraw passes in the current particle and is called before each particle is displayed on the screen.
```

This is working for this is working for other variables such as

```
                onDraw: function (p) {
            var y = -this.age * 3;
            p.size *= 0.98;
            p.color = 'rgb(255, ' + (y + 255) + ', 68)';
            p.opacity = 0.5 - (p.age / p.life * 0.4);
        }
```

But I cannot get it to work with p.direction.

Thanks for any help